# How to measure the force from outside that impact to a android phone (an android system)?

Tags: android

I've read the Motion Sensors of Android but can't figure out how to measure the vibration (or value of force) of phone when it's got a force impact on .

Comment: Do you understand the physics of force and acceleration?

Comment: Yes.i think i don't understand correctly. But how can i measure it

Comment: i don't know how to  measure the Vibration of  phone, like this app do: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.sira.vibration&hl=vi

Comment: You will have to use the values given by the sensors and apply the appropriate physical calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The Sensors API will tell you the acceleration of the phone. If you also know the phone's mass, you can calculate the amount of force using Newton's Laws of Motion.

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Comment: @KỳĐoànVăn I gave an example in my answer. More specifically, if you know the phone's mass and acceleration, you will need Newton's 2nd Law to calculate the force. With more complex motion, you need more complex mathematics. This means you must study textbooks on the subjects related to what you want. This site is not appropriate for writing textbook-sized answers.